# Swift can't read from csv

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, createml

I am trying to read from a csv file to do ML tabular classification and get the following error:

```
Playground execution terminated: An error was thrown and was not caught:
▿ MLCreateError
  ▿ generic : 1 element
    - reason : "Cannot open /Users/.../Desktop/HouseData.csv for read. Cannot open /Users/.../Desktop/HouseData.csv for reading"
```

Here is the code in the playground I use:

```
import CreateML
import Foundation

let houseData = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/.../Desktop/HouseData.csv"))
let (trainingCSVData, testCSVData) = houseData.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 0)
let pricer = try MLRegressor(trainingData: houseData, targetColumn: "MEDV")
let csvMetadata = MLModelMetadata(author: "aaa bbb", shortDescription: "A model used to determine the price of a house based on some features.", version: "1.0")
try pricer.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/.../Desktop/HousePricer.mlmodel"), metadata: csvMetadata)
```

Please help! 
Thank you

Comment: Try to open your csv file as explained here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/createml/creating_a_model_from_tabular_data

Comment: using playgrounds I don't have a bundle

Comment: You can use a Bundle with Playground, see the link.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the csv file to Documents instead of Desktop worked.